# Mac mini (2006) crashes after a while

Tags: hardware, mac-mini

I have an early 2006 Mac mini (A1176, Macmini1,1). It seems to work fine for a while, but it eventually starts crashing, then booting right back up again. It will either crash somewhere along the Apple Logo boot screen, it it'll just barely get to the Desktop before crashing again. At that point I just unplug it and put it away for the day. Coming back the next day, it starts off working fine, then eventually it starts crashing. I also notice that the fans ramp up a lot during this loop and it heats up as well.

Any idea what this might be? Unfortunately, I'm unable to run AHT at all, it refuses to acknowledge the D key even when I have a bootable USB drive that's has a working copy of its original restore disc (with the AHT on it).

Updates: trying to diagnose what's wrong with the machine, I never see anything of note in the log after a crash, the GPU/RAM area seems particularly hot after it boot loops for a while. One time, I got a corrupt screen output. Sometimes it fails to boot and just does a flashing LED light.

Update #2: I tried booting from a different drive, no success. I even SMART verified the internal HD. I tried using only one RAM stick, each in different RAM slots. Tried installing 10.6, it won't ever fully install, always crashes.

Comment: If it still crashes when you boot from an external drive, or from the DVD, then it's a hardware fault. If it works well initially, but then crashes more frequently after running for a while, that does sound like an overheating problem.

Comment: You would have to look at the system logs.  What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: @benwiggy I doubt overheating is the issue. I was able to run a benchmark earlier in the day and it was able ramp the fan up, then ramp the fan down. I don't believe there are any issues with the internal Hd, but I'll have to test booting from an external drive.

Comment: @Allan using 10.4.5. I tried looking at the logs and they didn't really say anything of note.

Comment: @At0mic Tiger, 10.4 went to 10.4.11.  I doubt upgrading would fix the problem, but would seem a good idea to be at the latest and greatest. I would not upgrade until you get the machine working. Don't want to create a worse mess.

Comment: (point 1) I hold down the d key then power on. (point 2) You did hold down the option key to get in the startup display, select your startup drive then press and hold the d key?

Comment: @historystamp I'd rather wait on trying to install anything until I can make sure it doesn't crash. I have everything related to holding the D key down, nothing works.

Comment: When did Apple begin to install hardware tests on on the drive?

Comment: @historystamp I don't know but /System/Library/CoreServices/.diagnostics exists, so it shouldn't be the problem.